# order by not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, subsonic, sql-order-by

I am using an objectdatasource with a gridview to get data from my orm class, but I cannot get it to order by properly. 
I am using the code below but it does not come up in descending order like I have specified below. What am I missing?  Using subsonic 2.1

```
<DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, True)> Public Function FetchByPatID(ByVal PatientID As Object) As VisitCollection

    Dim coll As VisitCollection = New VisitCollection().Where("PatientID", PatientID).Load()
    **OrderBy.Desc(Visit.DosColumn)**
    Return coll

End Function
```

Comment: is Visit.DosColumn something sortable?

Comment: And what is OrderBy.Desc?
I'm not a VB guru, but is that using the LINQ `OrderBy`? If so, LINQ's OrderBy only actually does anything when you iterate over the result (it returns a new sequence without altering the original sequence).

Answer (score 4):

The order by is executed against the database as part of your query. It needs to be added before the .Load() method is called.

```
Dim coll As VisitCollection = New VisitCollection().Where("PatientID", PatientID).OrderByDesc(Visit.Columns.DosColumn).Load()
```

Answer (score 2):

Ranomore is correct.  You must specify the OrderBy before you actually execute the command as the ordering is done on the database.

If you are using SubSonic 2.1 I much prefer the new syntax that has been added which makes the Query much more readable

```
SubSonic.Select.AllColumnsFrom(Of Visit)().Where(Visit.PatientIDColumn).isEqualTo(PatientID).OrderByDesc(Visit.DosColumn.ColumnName).ExecuteAsCollection(Of VisitCollection)()
```